# How to make K-mean image processing algorithm faster in my android application

Tags: java, android, opencv, optimization, k-means

I want to have a faster way to apply k-mean to a image and display on the screen. I want to have a opencv for android solutions. My code has a 30s run time on smart phone. I want to run it around 1 or 2s.

I already had code for the K-mean and displayed on the screen using opencv. But I need it to be faster. I think the way it label the image and display took to much time.

```java
public void k_Mean(){
        Mat rgba = new Mat();
        Mat mHSV = new Mat();

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),images[current_image]);
        Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap,rgba);

        //must convert to 3 channel image
        Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, mHSV, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB,3);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, mHSV, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV,3);
        Mat clusters = cluster(mHSV, 3).get(0);
        Utils.matToBitmap(clusters,outputBitmap);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(outputBitmap);
    }


    public  List<Mat> cluster(Mat cutout, int k) {
        Mat samples = cutout.reshape(1, cutout.cols() * cutout.rows());
        Mat samples32f = new Mat();
        samples.convertTo(samples32f, CvType.CV_32F, 1.0 / 255.0);

        Mat labels = new Mat();
        //criteria means the maximum loop
        TermCriteria criteria = new TermCriteria(TermCriteria.COUNT, 20, 1);
        Mat centers = new Mat();
        Core.kmeans(samples32f, k, labels, criteria, 1, Core.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);

        return showClusters(cutout, labels, centers);
    }

    private static List<Mat> showClusters (Mat cutout, Mat labels, Mat centers) {
        centers.convertTo(centers, CvType.CV_8UC1, 255.0);
        centers.reshape(3);

        System.out.println(labels + "labels");

        List<Mat> clusters = new ArrayList<Mat>();
        for(int i = 0; i < centers.rows(); i++) {
            clusters.add(Mat.zeros(cutout.size(), cutout.type()));
        }

        Map<Integer, Integer> counts = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < centers.rows(); i++) counts.put(i, 0);

        int rows = 0;
        for(int y = 0; y < cutout.rows(); y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < cutout.cols(); x++) {
                int label = (int)labels.get(rows, 0)[0];
                int r = (int)centers.get(label, 2)[0];
                int g = (int)centers.get(label, 1)[0];
                int b = (int)centers.get(label, 0)[0];
                counts.put(label, counts.get(label) + 1);
                clusters.get(label).put(y, x, b, g, r);
                rows++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(counts);
        return clusters;
    }
```

My output is correct. I wander if there is any faster way to do this. My other image processing algorithm run time is less than 1s.

Comment: whats the raw size of rgba? if it is like 20 + mega pixel and you are asking for 1 sec solution. the answer is impossible.  The alternative is (1) you can resize it down, (2) you can use the GPU inside your phone to handle

Comment: original size is 639 * 1852 but when I print out the Bitmap size it is 5431 * 1680. Is there any method that I can reduce the size?

Comment: ....see opencv resize function. https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize  not sure which size you process it on. But i think you can try lower resolution and get faster speed.